# Вопрос по культуре речи

Tags: языкознание

1. Почему Россия, но русский и Русь? Есть ли слова с этими корнями?
2. Что означает корень моск? И есть ли в современном языке слова с корнем моск?
3. Из каких языков было наибольшее заимствование в русский алфавит?
4. Укажите разницу между старославянским и церковнославянским языками? Примеры слов, судьба языков?

Comment: Разделите свой вопрос на 4, отвечать сразу на все долго, и не всем интересно. По первому вопросу можете посмотреть по [ссылке](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/19/этимология-почему-россия-пишется-с-двумя-с)

Answer (score 1):

Старославянский язык - это первый славянский литературный язык, созданный на основе болгарских диалектов с привлечением элементов современного на тот момент греческого языка. Старославянский язык был искусственным языком со своего первого дня существования, хотя в Болгарии его часто называют древнеболгарским языком. Широко обобщая, это язык действительно в какой-то мере был древнеболгарским языком, но только если убрать искусственно привнесённые в него элементы из греческого  на уровне лексики, фонетики, морфологии и синтаксиса.

Как бы там ни было, различия между славянскими языками (вернее, диалектами, из которых складывались эти языки) в IX веке были минимальными по сравнению с тем, насколько эти языки отличаются сейчас. Люди понимали написанное и сказанное на старославянском почти без перевода. Старославянский язык был фактически лингва франка славян. Некоторое время, потраченное на изучение азбуки и Св. Писания устраняло даже эту преграду, а школы на Руси были повсюду, грамотность была если не всеобщей, то вполне распространённой. Так было в период с IX по XI века, возможно даже до XII века. Вот этими временными рамками и ограничивается существование старославянского языка.

Начиная с XII века и по сегодняшний день речь идёт у же о церковнославянском языке, причём нужно уточнять, о каком изводе идёт речь. Русская православная церковь пользуется русским изводом, сербская - сербским и т. д. Больше всего от древней формы отошёл именно современный болгарский язык.

"Извод" - это национальный вариант церковнославянского языка, различия между изводами касаются прежде всего произношения отдельных слов, вызванных различиями в фонетических системах этих языков. Самый простой пример - произношение того, что обозначает буква Щ. Для русских - это длинный мягкий звук [ш':], как и в современном русском языке, а для западных славян (болгар, сербов) - это, как всегда, сочетание звуков [шт].
Подробно прочитайте здесь: http://www.philol.msu.ru/~slavphil/books/stsl_csl_web.pdf

И вот здесь: http://traditio-ru.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Answer (score 0):

1. Тут уже "обсасывали" с разных сторон. Попробуйте поискать.
2. Корень "моск" встречается у прибалтов в самых разных значениях от "узел" до "болото".
3. Современный русский алфавит разработан греками.
4. Полагаю, что церковнославянский сильнее "засорён" эллинизмами. Но конкретных примеров привести не смогу. Впрочем, думаю, что людей, лучше владеющих данной темой, на форуме хватает.